# Settings blocks are rendered with white background

Tags: 14.04, unity

Has anyone seen this problem before? Suddenly, white blocks are rendered in my 'Settings' application. Why is the rendering so strange? It should be transparent, I think?

I'm using Ubuntu:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
```

[image: ubuntu_settings_block]

Comment: I also notice checkboxes and radiobuttons are not rendering correctly anymore. The white background is just not visible over there.

Comment: I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS which solved the problem.